# Let $f(x)=(x+1)^2$. Prove that f is continuous at 0

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I've started work from the definition, so for all $ϵ>0$, there is $δ>0$ such that $0<|x|<δ$, then $|(x+1)^2-(0+1)^2|<ϵ$.

Then by expanding, $|x^2+2x|<ϵ$, $|x||x+2|<ϵ$, and by definition $|x|<δ$, so i'm trying to find an $|x+2|$. Here is where i'm having trouble - as the point it is continuous at is zero I don't know how to use the $x+2$. Am I right in saying $|x+2|<δ+2$, so $|x||x+2|<δ(δ+2)$ and working from there?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, since the triangle inequality gives you $|x+2|\le |x|+|2|<\delta+2$

Comment: Ok so from this can you pick ϵ=δ(δ+2) and then that proves the statement?

Comment: Yes, that's accurate.

Comment: Great thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The argument so far is quite incomplete. Picking $\epsilon=\delta(2+\delta)$ is problematic, since we are **given** $\epsilon$ and must find a suitable $\delta$,

We will first of all make sure that $\delta\le 1$. Then if $|x-0|\lt \delta$, it will follow that $|2+x|\lt 3$, and therefore if $x\ne 0$ then 
$|x||2+x|\lt 3|x|$.

Finally, we make sure that $3|x|\lt \epsilon$, that is, that $|x|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Putting things together, we let $\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\right)$. If $|x|\lt \delta$ we have $|x||2+x|\lt \epsilon$.